# Setting up dev environment for Android project using Spring Tool Suite and Maven

Tags: java, android, spring, maven, installation

I am new to Spring framework, Android and Maven.

I would like to setup an environment for developing Android apps with Spring Tool Suite and Maven.

I followed the guides on http://spring.io/ but I did not succeed.

This is a newbie question: Could anybody help me setting up the environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are are looking for a quick and easy way to get started with an android app, why dont you try http://www.androidbootstrap.com

It uses gradle (much like maven),

That should get you going

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I need to use Maven and I would like to know what's going on under the hood.